# grep returns empty response

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, grep

I have below code which reads file `ctakes-backlog-new.lst` line by line and grep full matching string from file `without_symlink.lst` and loads the result in `ctakes-backlog-new.lst`. Both files are sorted. However I get empty response when running below code.

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
    then
        echo "Filename is missing."
        usage
        exit 1
    else
        fileName="$1"
fi

while read line;
#echo "$line"
  do
    grep -w "$line" 06-09-2021/without_symlink.lst >> 06-09-2021/ctakes_full_file_name.lst
  done < "$fileName"
```

Command I run: `./populate_full_file_name.sh 06-09-2021/ctakes-backlog-new.lst`

When I run command manually for single line like `grep -w "77-010_M0_1_arm_1" 06-09-2021/without_symlink.lst >> 06-09-2021/ctakes_full_file_name.lst` it works fine and loads the result (77-010_M0_1_arm_1.60c7144c9ff3060521b0b825149f7d7ee60e5afd.pdf) in `06-09-2021/ctakes-backlog-new.lst`

I have tried wrapping `"$line"` in double quote but did not make any difference. eg: `grep -w "$line" 06-09-2021/without_symlink.lst >> 06-09-2021/ctakes_full_file_name.lst`

Example input:

```
13-013_M48_9_arm_1
16-039_M42_8_arm_1
77-010_M0_1_arm_1
```

Expected output:

```
13-013_M48_9_arm_1.d4b2f31683ba73f7919d46a2514d0742c77029a3.pdf
16-039_M42_8_arm_1.546b57794b71b7a17235368900f5f9c4d34a2a87.pdf
77-010_M0_1_arm_1.60c7144c9ff3060521b0b825149f7d7ee60e5afd.pdf
```

Comment: are you sure that `grep -w $line "77-010_M0_1_arm_1"` is the right command? In the script you have `06-09-2021/without_symlink.lst` as the file. Show the full script, how you run it and some sample input files

Comment: I have updated the question with correct command and some example input and expected outputs.

Comment: `if [ -z $1 ]` won't always do what you think it will. If `$1` is a string of spaces the result is `if [ -z ]`, which is true even though `$1` is not empty. Furthermore, if `$1` is an alphanumeric value that contains spaces the expression will fail with an error. Always double-quote your variables when you use them and these problems won't occur, i.e. `if [ -z "$1" ]`, later `done < "$fileName"`, etc.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have updated the code but I don't think that is the actual issue I am facing here.

Comment: Is it possible that `06-09-2021/ctakes-backlog-new.lst` has DOS-style (CRLF) line endings? Check with `file 06-09-2021/ctakes-backlog-new.lst` for example.

Comment: You've edited your code to quote variables for the two _examples_ I gave, but you've not applied the rule, _always double-quite variables when you use them_". There are other places even more needy of the quoting

Comment: @steeldriver could be. I have actually copied column from csv to txt file and saved as txt would that make any difference? How would I convert the file to normal style which grep command can recognize?

Comment: @ShyamBhimani that could make a difference - depending exactly how you copied and/or saved the column. You can use `dos2unix` (which permanently changes the line endings) or pipe the file through another tool such as `sed` or `tr` to remove the CR characters on the fly. If your shell supports process substitution you can do that right in the redirection ex. in bash, replace `< "$fileName"` with `< <(sed 's/\r$//' "$fileName")`

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you so much. That worked perfect!

Comment: @ShyamBhimani be aware that it's not a *good* way to match lines from one file in another - please consider doing something like `sed 's/\r$//' "$fileName" | grep -wFf - 06-09-2021/without_symlink.lst` instead